# find and display datarows in datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datatable

I faced to issue of displaying datarows from `DataTable` from `DataSet`. I used a temporary table. I found rows  that I need by `id` and copy it to temporary table and then diplay in `DataGridView`. Is there any way to find and display rows that I need in `DataGridView` directly from `DataTable` from `DataSet` without using any temporary `DataTable's`? I've tried to do this by hiding and unhiding rows in `DataGridView`, but sadly it didn't worked out

```
private DataTable tblFiltered = 
  ds.Tables("GRAPHICS").AsEnumerable().Where(row => 
  row.Field<int>("GRAPHIC_ID") == graphId && row.Field<int> 
 ("GRAPHIC_ID")).CopyToDataTable;
```

Comment: You can create a `DataView` and use [`DataView.RowFilter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataview.rowfilter?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that DataSet 'ds' containing Table 'GRAPHICS',We can use DataView to Display filtered records in DataGridView. Ex.

```
int graphId = 2;  //Assuming

DataView dv = ds.Tables["GRAPHICS"].AsDataView();
dv.RowFilter = "GRAPHIC_ID = " + graphId;     //RowFilter :: Expression used to filter which rows are viewed !!        
dataGridView.DataSource = dv.ToTable();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use filter
`(DatagridView.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("GRAPHIC_ID= '{0}'", graphId);`

Comment: Should not use `as` without a null check (or `?.`).